# Random spawn algorithm does not generate correctly

Tags: java, if-statement

I have this code to spawn a 'tree' in my Java game; it works and spawns a 'tree'. I decided to make a random number generator up to 30 which would spawn that many 'trees'. However, when I run my code, I get no error but the 'trees' don't spawn. The spawning algorithm can be found below.

```
private void generateLevel() {
    int dungeonCoord = dungeonSpawn.nextInt(height * width);
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            tiles[x + y * width] = Tile.GRASS.getId();
            tiles[dungeonCoord] = Tile.TUNNEL.getId();
             while(tCount < tRan)   {
                 System.out.println(tRan);
                 tCount ++;
                 int treeX = treeSpawn.nextInt(width * 5);
                 if(treeX < 256)    {
                     treeX = 256;
                }else   {
                    tiles[treeX] = Tile.LOG.getId();
                    tiles[treeX + width] = Tile.LOG.getId();
                    tiles[treeX + width + width] = Tile.LOG.getId();
                    tiles[treeX - width] = Tile.LEAVES.getId();
                    tiles[treeX - width] = Tile.LEAVES.getId();
                    tiles[treeX - width - width] = Tile.LEAVES.getId();
                    tiles[treeX - width - width + 1] = Tile.LEAVES.getId();
                    tiles[treeX - width - width - 1] = Tile.LEAVES.getId();
                    tiles[treeX - width + 1] = Tile.LEAVES.getId();
                    tiles[treeX - width + 2] = Tile.LEAVES.getId();
                    tiles[treeX - width - 1] = Tile.LEAVES.getId();
                    tiles[treeX - width - 2] = Tile.LEAVES.getId();
                    tiles[treeX + 1] = Tile.LEAVES.getId();
                    tiles[treeX - 1] = Tile.LEAVES.getId();
                    tiles[treeX - width - width - width] = Tile.LEAVES.getId(); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How everything is declared:

```
private byte[] tiles;
public int width;
public int height;
public boolean generateTree = true;
Random treeSpawn = new Random();
Random dungeonSpawn = new Random();
Random numTrees = new Random();
int tCount = 0;
int tRan = numTrees.nextInt(30);
```

The `treeSpawn` boolean is for later on.

Comment: How have you determined that the trees aren't spawning?

Comment: Not entirely sure what's causing the problem from what I'm reading, however the statement `if ( treeX < 256 ) { treeX = 256; } else ...` would not behave the way I think you'd expect. If `treeX` is less than 256, your trees would never be drawn because you used `else`. Based on the way you set `treeX` to 256 inside the `if` statement, I'm guessing the `else` was unintentional and you still want to draw the tree.

Comment: Also, looking at your code, the general formula for a `tiles` index given X and Y is `tiles[x + y * width]`; but the way you are indexing tiles doesn't seem right (or you haven't fully explained the expected behavior). Why does `treeX` have range 0 to width*5? What's with all the adding and subtracting of `width`?

Comment: Im trying to draw the tree near where my player spawns so i can look ati it, thats why there's all the - widths and the treeX = 256 is to make sure the value isnt below 0 to ensure i dont get out of bound errors when spawning as the spawn is less than 0

Comment: But why do you set `treeX` to 256 then proceed to not draw the tree?

Comment: i set the treeX to 256 then i try to draw the tree, thats why i posted here, its not drawing 

 tiles[x + y * width] = Tile.GRASS.getId(); 
makes everything grass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer comes from what I can ascertain in the comments.

The code, as follows:

```
if(treeX < 256)    {
    treeX = 256;
} else   {
```

means that, if `treeX` is less than 256, your code doesn't even *attempt* to draw the tree. In order to draw the tree, you need to remove the `else` (which is ignored when your `if` statement is evaluated to be `true`) so your `while` loop looks as follows:

```
while(tCount < tRan)   {
    System.out.println(tRan);
    tCount ++;
    int treeX = treeSpawn.nextInt(width * 5);

    if(treeX < 256)    {
        treeX = 256;
    }

    tiles[treeX] = Tile.LOG.getId();
    tiles[treeX + width] = Tile.LOG.getId();
    tiles[treeX + width + width] = Tile.LOG.getId();
    tiles[treeX - width] = Tile.LEAVES.getId();
    ... // Rest of the tree drawing code
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was part of the problem, also realised i was drawing the random number of trees in one place :/